# Building custom RPM but the package is empty?

Tags: apache, fedora, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am trying to build an rpm for a compiled version of apache.
I want the rpm to build it in /opt/apache....
I am able to create the RPM file itself but when I do a rpm -qpl on the file it shows up as empty.

Here is my spec file:

```
Name:           custom-http
Version:        2.2.25
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        A custom build of Apache

License:        NA
URL:            http://x.x.x.x:/repo2
Source0:        http://x.x.x.x:/repo2/httpd-2.2.25.tar.gz

BuildRequires:  xfce4-dev-tools apr-util openssl-devel

%description
Custom compiled version of Apache version 2.2.25

%prep
%setup -n httpd-2.2.25

%build
./configure --disable-rpaths --with-included-apr --enable-mods-shared=all --with-mpm=prefork --enable-ssl --prefix=/opt/apache --enable-so

make %{?_smp_mflags}

%install
make install

%clean

%files

%doc

%changelog
* Thu Jan 30 2014 name <email address>
- First attempt
```

~

Comment: It might be easier to find an existing `httpd` source RPM, take out the `.spec` file, and tweak the install path. Then you're not reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to install the files to the buildroot when doing `make install`, since you don't want the files to be installed in the actual filesystem root when building the package. 
This means that you have to replace the `make install` with `make install DESTDIR=%{buildroot}`, which you can also write simply as `%make_install` (to see what a macro expands to, you can do `rpm -E <macro>`, i.e.

```
$ rpm -E %make_install
/usr/bin/make install DESTDIR=$HOME/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}.x86_64
```

).

Then, as Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams said, you will need to populate the `%files` section. To find out what you have to write there, just do a build from the tarball, install it in some temporary directory (using `DESTDIR` when calling `make install`), and then list the installed files. Read i.e. [1] for more on this.

Other notes:

- `%doc` actually belongs to the `%files` section (judging from the extra spacing you added around `%doc`, it is not clear whether you are aware of this).
- `%clean` is not necessary anymore if you are targeting a recent rpm distro (i.e. Fedora > F13, RHEL >= 6).

[1] http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package#.25files_section

Answer (score 2):

If you continue down whatever it is you're using to learn how to create RPMs, it will talk about populating `%files`. Read that part.

Comment: Just found a good tutorial. However, since I am unpackaging it to /opt/apache I am not sure what should be in the spec file:      %files /httpd-2.2.25/
/httpd-2.2.25/

Comment: I need this RPM to compile from the tar.gz file and install accordingly.